# Debugging DNS stub resolver

Tags: networking, 22.04, dns

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.6 and I'm facing issues with the DNS stub resolver.

Using the default settings, I cannot access several webpages. However, when I add the google DNS address to `/etc/resolv.conf` (which is a link to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`), things work perfectly. However, this is obviously more of a patch than a solution, but it points to the fact that `systemd-resolved` is not working properly.

Could anyone give me some ideas on what to try to debug this?

Thanks!